# How to save and open jtextpane content to/from an external file which contains Bold,Italics,Underline text, images and other styled content?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I am developing a Wordpad application using Java Swing.

I am using JTextPane component. I have added the code for Bold, Italics, Underline.  I am adding the code to insert images in all the formats.

My expected scenario: I want to save the document with all these styled content with the extension '.doc' (or)'.docx'. And I want to read and open the document which contains these types of styled content like Bold, Italic, underline text and images, bullet points etc..

I don't think it can be done with HTMLEditorKit().

Can anyone help with the sample code for saving and reading these styled contents to/from external file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `JTextPane` supports HTML and RTF formats only. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ViewingRTFformat.htm) you can find an example of reading RTF file into JTextPane.

Comment: You can do it by using docx4j.